# Reset IP on an Avocent DSR2035

Tags: kvm

Got this legacy Avocent DSR2035 KVM over IP. Works! Anyone knows how I edit the TCPIP setting on this machine? I have access to the console, it works, but there is no IP settings in any of the menu!

Answer (score 0):

It took some time to figure this out. I had to upgrade firmware first and that was done through the setup port in the back and using a special cable that I built. After the fw update, there were network settings in the standard interface.